# Uninitialized register variable warning

Tags: c++, initialization, compiler-warnings

I was working with a old codebase where I encountered few line of code which was causing lot of repeated warnings during compilation.

```
#define EXAMPLE(_ptr) \
{                               \
    register uintptr_t      *__sp __asm__("sp");        \
    (_ptr[0]) = (uintptr_t) __sp;                       \
    asm volatile("sw $a0,%0" : "=m" (_ptr[1])); \
    //SOME OTHER CODE HERE
}
```

the warning was:

```
warning: ‘__sp’ may be used uninitialized in this function
```

Can anyone help me in understanding what is happening in this code block and how to remove this warning.

Comment: If it was me, I would try to refactor the code to not need inline assembly at all. And more importantly, I would try to refactor the code to not need to use macros.

Comment: which compiler/version are you using?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, completely removing all inline assembly or macros is not really possible in my case. So I was more interested in resolving the warning at least.

P.W, compilation uses gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)

Comment: Trying to read the stack pointer in c code this way is not a supported use of [local register variables](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html): *The only supported use for this feature is to specify registers for input and output operands when calling Extended asm*.  Like spd says, I'd try to re-work this.  If you MUST keep this, maybe something like `asm("" : "+r"(__sp))` would satisfy the compiler?

Comment: You might also try adding the `inline-assembly` tag and the hw platform you are working on (is that mips?) to your question.  That might get you attention from people who could help you re-work this.  There's got to be a better solution than explicitly doing something the docs say you shouldn't, then covering that fact up by tricking the compiler.  While that might work today (or at least seem to), updates to the compiler or even minor changes to the surrounding code could produce really weird (and hard to track down) errors.